# White border on right (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
html, body{width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

and

```
#wrap{margin: 0 auto;width:100%;}
```

However, when I load my page, I can see a white border on the right of the browser using the horizontal scroll bars. I added a border around both my body and wrap and it goes all around my content but it does not "include" the white border. Why is that? I want to remove this annoying bug.

EDIT: I found the problem. I had the following:

```
    <div class="section" id="home">
    <ul class="arrows">
        <li><a href="#test"><img class="arrows" src="/Content/arrows.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS was:

```
#home ul.arrows{list-style-type:none;width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:40px;border:2px solid blue;}
#home img{width:34px;height:35px;display:none;border-style:none;}
```

So it was taking too much space. How can I center my image without using the width:100%?

Comment: do you got a link??  can't really tell from your code tehre

Comment: No, please don't *link* to the page. Instead, add more code to the question so we (and future users, after you've fixed your site) can reproduce the problem!

Comment: put border:0 on html, body?

Comment: put it in a jsfiddle: fork this one - http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/KBWHN/